# jfreechart at client side

Tags: jfreechart, gantt-chart

I have implemented gantt chart using jfreechart. I want to know how can I get this chart accessed from client side. Also I do not want just image of the chart, I also want the zooming functionality alongside it. How to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: I'd use [tag:javawebstart].

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please elaborate more?

While minimally interactive charts are possible in a servlet context, a fully interactive desktop application may be made available from the server via [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). Among the JFreeChart [samples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), the [JWS demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) best illustrates the potential.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Here are the details. My ganttchart creation logic is at server side. I get all the functionality of this chart at server side(e.g. zooming the chart, rendering the chart bars etc) because I have chart object at server side. However I do not get this power at client side because I am just sending produced PNG image to client side. In order to achieve that, as per you said I probably will have to go with JWS approach. But still, isn't there any other approach besides JWS?

Comment: @genonymous: Not that I'm aware of. I see the servlet & JWS approaches as complementary. I usually just have the JWS app connect to the same server for data, but an embedded database like H2 would work, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must catch client event and handle it from server side, and of course reload the image with the changes.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that but that will increase the response time to the client request greatly. e.g. Client mat send many zoom areas and for each of that request server will have to produce image again and again and then send it to client side.